In Express JS why does axios response.data work without await, but fetch response.json() requires await?
I'm implementing an API call in my Express.js application and noticed different behavior between axios and fetch:
Specifically, in this Express server code from my original codes, when using fetch, const data = response.json() without await returns an undefined object and doesn't work properly. However, with axios, const data = response.data; works correctly to retrieve the data object even without using await.
(axios vs fetch)
// axios
const response = await axios.get(url);
const data = response.data;  // works
// const data = await response.data;  // works

// fetch
// const response = await fetch(url);
// const data = response.json();  // doesn't work, return an undefined object
// const data = await response.json();  // works

I tried implementing these 4 patterns of data retrieval and confirmed that 3 patterns definitely work, but as technical knowledge, I would like to understand the fundamental reason why the fetch implementation without await doesn't work.
[original codes, for reproducing the behavior]
(server.js)
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import path from 'path';
import axios from 'axios';

const app = express();
const API_KEY = 'MY_API_KEY';
const PORT = 3000;

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const __dirname = path.resolve();

// Genre IDs for TMDB API
const genres = {
    'action': 28,
    'comedy': 35,
    'drama': 18,
    'horror': 27,
    'romance': 10749,
    'science fiction': 878
};

async function searchMovies(genre, year, rating) {
    try {
        const baseUrl = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie`;
        const queryParams = new URLSearchParams({
            api_key: API_KEY,
            with_genres: genres[genre],
            primary_release_year: year,
            'vote_average.gte': rating,
            sort_by: 'vote_average.desc',
            page: 1
        });
        const url = `${baseUrl}?${queryParams.toString()}`;

        console.log(url);

        // axios
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        // both work
        const data = response.data;  // works
        // const data = await response.data;  // works

        // fetch
        // const response = await fetch(url);
        // const data = response.json();  // doesn't work, return an undefined object
        // const data = await response.json();  // works


        if (data.total_results === 0) {
            throw new Error('No movies found matching your criteria');
        }

        return data.results.slice(0, 10); // Return top 10 results
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error.response?.data?.message || error.message);
    }
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render(__dirname + '/movies.ejs', { 
        genres: Object.keys(genres),
        currentYear: new Date().getFullYear()
    });
});

app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { genre, year, rating } = req.body;
        
        // Validation
        if (!genre || !year || !rating) {
            throw new Error('All fields are required');
        }

        if (year < 1900 || year > new Date().getFullYear()) {
            throw new Error('Invalid year');
        }

        if (rating < 0 || rating > 10) {
            throw new Error('Rating must be between 0 and 10');
        }

        const movies = await searchMovies(genre, year, rating);

        res.render(__dirname + '/movies.ejs', {
            genres: Object.keys(genres),
            currentYear: new Date().getFullYear(),
            movies: movies,
            searchParams: { genre, year, rating }
        });

    } catch (error) {
        res.render(__dirname + '/movies.ejs', {
            genres: Object.keys(genres),
            currentYear: new Date().getFullYear(),
            error: error.message,
            searchParams: req.body
        });
    }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});



(movies.ejs)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Movie Search</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Movie Search</h1>
        
        <form class="search-form" action="/" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="genre">Genre:</label>
                <select name="genre" id="genre" required>
                    <option value="">Select a genre</option>
                    <% genres.forEach(genre => { %>
                        <option value="<%= genre %>" 
                            <%= locals.searchParams?.genre === genre ? 'selected' : '' %>>
                            <%= genre.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + genre.slice(1) %>
                        </option>
                    <% }) %>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="year">Release Year:</label>
                <input type="number" 
                       name="year" 
                       id="year" 
                       min="1900" 
                       max="<%= currentYear %>" 
                       value="<%= locals.searchParams?.year || currentYear %>" 
                       required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="rating">Minimum Rating (0-10):</label>
                <input type="number" 
                       name="rating" 
                       id="rating" 
                       min="0" 
                       max="10" 
                       step="0.1" 
                       value="<%= locals.searchParams?.rating || 7.0 %>" 
                       required>
            </div>

            <button type="submit">Search Movies</button>
        </form>

        <% if (locals.error) { %>
            <div class="error"><%= error %></div>
        <% } %>

        <% if (locals.movies) { %>
            <h2>Search Results</h2>
            <div class="movie-grid">
                <% movies.forEach(movie => { %>
                    <div class="movie-card">
                        <img class="movie-poster" 
                             src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500<%= movie.poster_path %>" 
                             alt="<%= movie.title %> poster">
                        <div class="movie-info">
                            <h3 class="movie-title"><%= movie.title %></h3>
                            <p><strong>Rating:</strong> <%= movie.vote_average %>/10 
                               (<%= movie.vote_count %> votes)</p>
                            <p><strong>Release Date:</strong> 
                               <%= new Date(movie.release_date).toLocaleDateString() %></p>
                            <p><%= movie.overview %></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <% }) %>
            </div>
        <% } %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


(Just FYI, /public/main.css)
.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.search-form {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.form-group label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.form-group select,
.form-group input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.movie-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(280px, 1fr));
    gap: 20px;
}
.movie-card {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.movie-poster {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.movie-info {
    padding: 15px;
}
.movie-title {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.error {
    color: red;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ffebee;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
button {
    background: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button:hover {
    background: #45a049;
}



because you awaited the only promise axios returns i.e on axios.get in your case - fetch is not axios, therefore it doesn't have to work like axios, it can work in a more flexible manner

by the way, const x = await nonPromise is perfectly fine, useful say if nonPromise could either be a promise or not - not sure if that was confusing you

From a blog: Axios will automatically transforms the server's response data, while with Fetch, you need to call the response methods to parse the data.... -- As @JaromandaX already mentioned, just because they are used for similar things, they are not working the same.

@jabaa You are right! I deleted my misleading comment, thanks.

AXIOS
axios.get() returns Promise with the next response schema (docs):
{
  data: {},
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'ok',
  headers: {},
  config: {},
  request: {},
}


that's why you have to await only axios.get(), which will return you ready to use response
Fetch

fetch() is a Promise, contains Server response
json() is a Promise, contains response body content

fetch works differently, you have to do more manupulations to use needed data, but its more flexible, because you have direct access to the Server response

I understood very well, thank you!
